# How to calculate Confidence Interval for person-years for reinfection rate?

Tags: confidence-interval

I am calculating the 95% confidence interval for the reinfection rate in person-years. There were 3 individuals who became reinfected with HCV in the collective 1127.11 years to get a rate of 0.27 per 100 person-years (0.3/100 py). How would I calculate the 95% CI for the 0.3/100 py?

An example is "The overall incidence of reinfection was 9.8 per 100-PY (95% CI 4.7,18.2)." https://www.postersessiononline.eu/173580348_eu/congresos/ILC2019/aula/-SAT_266_ILC2019.pdf

I read I could use poisson distribution and got 0.56 and 0.04, but it is weak when the count is low? Thank you in advance.